# Using recursion and dynamic memory allocation of multidimensional arrays to find the determinant of an NxN matrix

Tags: c++, dynamic, recursion, determinants

I'm trying to write a program that can calculate the determinant of any NxN matrix regardless of the size but there's something wrong with the program and it crashes for any matrix with size greater than 1.

I'd be very grateful to anyone who can tell me what I'm doing wrong. I'm new to c++ and dynamic memory so, take it easy on me please (:.

Here's my program:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int determinant(int *matrix[], int size);
void ijMinor(int *matrix[], int *minorMatrix[], int size, int row, int column);

int main()
{
    int size;
    cout << "What is the size of the matrix for which you want to find the determinant?:\t";
    cin >> size;

    int **matrix;
    matrix = new int*[size];
    for (int i = 0 ; i < size ; i++)
        matrix[i] = new int[size];

    cout << "\nEnter the values of the matrix seperated by spaces:\n\n";
    for(int i = 0; i < size; i++)
        for(int j = 0; j < size; j++)
            cin >> matrix[i][j];

    cout << "\nThe determinant of the matrix is:\t" << determinant(matrix, size) << endl;

    return 0;
}

int determinant(int *matrix[], int size){
    if(size==1)return matrix[0][0];
    else{
        int result=0, sign=-1;
        for(int j = 0; j < size; j++){

            int **minorMatrix;
            minorMatrix = new int*[size-1];
            for (int k = 0 ; k < size-1 ; k++)
                matrix[k] = new int[size-1];

            ijMinor(matrix, minorMatrix, size, 0, j);

            sign*=-1;
            result+=sign*matrix[0][j]*determinant(minorMatrix, size-1);
            for(int i = 0; i < size-1; i++){
                delete minorMatrix[i];
            }
        }

        return result;
    }
}

void ijMinor(int *matrix[], int *minorMatrix[], int size, int row, int column){
    for(int i = 0; i < size; i++){
        for(int j = 0; j < size; j++){
            if(i < row){
                if(j < column)minorMatrix[i][j] = matrix[i][j];
                else if(j == column)continue;
                else minorMatrix[i][j-1] = matrix[i][j];
            }
            else if(i == row)continue;
            else{
                if(j < column)minorMatrix[i-1][j] = matrix[i][j];
                else if(j == column)continue;
                else minorMatrix[i-1][j-1] = matrix[i][j];
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I would first suggest refactoring to use [std::vector](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/vector/vector/), instead of dynamic memory based arrays, to eliminate the need to `new` and `delete`.

Comment: Always use `delete[]` when you did `new[]`.

Comment: Thanks for the help.. The program is working now

Answer (score 1):

Your `minorMatrix` consists of uninitialised pointers because of this:

```
minorMatrix = new int*[size-1];
for (int k = 0 ; k < size-1 ; k++)
    matrix[k] = new int[size-1];
```

`matrix[k]`should be `minorMatrix[k]`.

Comment: Thank you very much man. That did the trick. That's what happens when you copy and paste without making sure you changed every variable.

Answer (score 0):

You are better off using the C/C++ interfaces to BLAS/LAPACK Fortran libraries which do the best job at this task.

First the numerical method you have implemented in O(N!) in complexity, not to mention the numerical instabilities you will introduce;
real world systems (which invariably use BLAS packages underneath) approach the problem by first converting the NxN matrix to a upper/lower triangular form, and then finding the product of the main-diagonal elements.

Find references in the classic books 'Numerical Recipes,' or 'Matrix Computations.'

Comment: Thanks for the help and references. I'm only a beginner in programming, so I was just trying to test my understanding with the task. I wasn't trying to write the best or most efficient program for finding the determinant. Nevertheless, thank you very much and I'm sure I'll find the references you gave me very helpful.